# Since which version JRE supports AES128-CTR

Tags: java, aes, jsch

Troubleshooting "**algorithm negotiation fail**" error thrown by **JSCH**. The SSH server accepts aes128-ctr, aes192-ctr, and aes256-ctr. I suspect the JRE in client may be too old - I don't have access to the client box. I wrote a piece of code using JSCH 0.1.5 and JRE7 to connect to the same server and the connection actually went through.

Google won't give me an answer. Would you? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed the Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files for your JRE? You are restricted from accessing all the encryption algorithms until it is installed.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html

Comment: i checked it and it says only aes256 is unavailable if Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy File is not installed. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I believe it depends on the version of the JRE you are using. In 1.6 it lifted the restriction on symmetric algorithms above 128 bit(Ignoring SecureRandom).